How to extract pipe remnant from ground sleeve?
In Hurricane Beryl my Purple Martin birdhouse pole blew over when it broke off at the ground sleeve. In retrospect it was weakened by decades of metal fatigue and rust.
I would like to extract the remnant of the old pole from inside the ground sleeve so that I can re-use the sleeve for a replacement pole.
The pole is a 2 1/2 inch outside diameter galvanized steel pipe and the ground sleeve is a slightly larger diameter galvanized steel pipe anchored into the ground with concrete.  The ground sleeve is three feet long and the inner pipe extends down to the end of it. The sleeve sticks out of the ground 8 inches or so. Referring to the picture, one can see that the inner pipe snapped off about an inch below the upper end of the ground sleeve pipe (unsurprisingly, it broke at the weak spot, where the retaining bolt holes were).

The inner pipe is not extremely tight against the outer pipe - I can stick the end of a large screwdriver between them and get some relative motion by prying. But the max displacement between the two pipes I can get is pretty small, maybe an eighth of an inch.
So my question boils down to, what tool or method can I use to "grab hold" of the inner pipe to pull it out? I expect it to take significant force, so it needs to be a pretty strong "grab".  With the limited pipe-to-pipe gap and the amount the inner pipe is recessed, I can't get a pair of pliers on it, and I don't think the grip strength would be sufficient if I could.

Step zero is to spray some penetrating oil into the crack between the two pipes.  No matter what you try later, start by decreasing the friction between the two tubes.   I'd squirt some oil in there morning and night for a week before you try anything else.

I see there is a split in the outer tube. Is there another split opposite it under the rule? If so, maybe you could drill a hole through each side of the inner so as to put a rod through to pull on.

@AndrewMorton unfortunately those cutouts in the sleeve don't go any further down than the top of the inner pipe. The cutouts are where the retaining bolt went, and are therefore right at the level where it cracked off. Good idea though, the cutouts are not clearly shown in the picture.

I take it that removing the concrete block from the ground so that you can get to the other end of it and thus push the inner tube out would not be seen as a sensible option?

@AndrewMorton If I can't get it out, I'll have to dig another post hole and put in another ground sleeve - basically the same level of effort, but I end up with a new ground sleeve. So digging up the old one is pretty far down the list.

There were a lot of great answers posted here, that I am sure will help out future searchers with a similar problem.
With the limited tools and even more limited talent available to me, I couldn't do any of them however.
I ended up cutting off the cauliflowered bottom inch or so of the upper piece and inserting a smaller diameter steel pipe inside the two fragments. Then drilling holes and bolting them together. A lot like this answer suggested only inside instead of outside.


Can you reach/touch the bottom of the inner pipe? If so, something like a bearing puller or a slide pull hammer with outside facing jaws will work.
Picture of one for example only.

Found on image search for slide hammers. Is from stanzaniusa.com/products/art-171-slide-hammer

Good question, I have not tried to get down there. Will update post after investigating it.

@OrganicMarble   The easy way is to get a pipe that will fit over the ground sleeve instead of inside it.

That is a good thought too. I am trying to preserve the option of getting a replacement lower section of the existing pole, but it may not be practical to do that.

I quite like this idea, but working from the example photo would suggest (a) grinding one side off that end effector leaving a single hook and (b) if necessary extending the length with threaded rod and a coupler.

I had to go down a full three feet to get to the bottom of the hole, and there's water down there, so I'm still not sure if I can get under it. I'm looking at right-angle pry-bars to try it, but so far the ones I've seen that are long enough, are too "wide" to fit into the inner pipe.

Hence use a slide hammer and hook as suggested by the answer. If you can /wiggle/ the pipe it should be extractable, although if you can only /deflect/ it (whereupon it springs back) it might be more difficult.

Please provide attribution of the image source unless you created the image yourself.

The first idea that comes to me is to weld a "handle" to the inner tube.
The access is enough for stick or wire feed welding, just take care not to weld both tubes together.

That's a great approach but I know nothing about welding and don't have the equipment. I'll ask around my friends.

It depends on how tightly stuck the inner pipe is, but a couple of options not already suggested (but related in principle to the rubber expansion plug suggestion) that you might be able to quickly try with stuff you already have:

Using a tool with long handles and a pivot point, like pliers, bolt cutters, tin snips, etc, simply open the tool so that the working end expands and grips the inside of the pipe, then pull it out. There won't be a lot of grip with this one, but it could work if the inner pipe is loose enough. You may be able to wrap the head of the tool in something rubbery to give it a little more grip
Use a few pieces of scrap wood to form a wedge in the pipe. The central piece will have a piece of rope attached that you can pull up on, and you can press down on the side pieces to wedge them tightly into place. Then as you lift the rope tied to the central piece, it'll force the side pieces against the wall of the pipe. As long as the friction between the wood and the pipe is high enough it should lift out the pipe.



These are good. I was trying to think of some way to get an expanding thing down in there (an expanding rubber stopper was already suggested).

The second idea with wedges is basically the same as a quill stem from older-style bicycles.  Downside is this will exert a lot of sideways force, and OP's photo shows its very thin-walled tube (I suspect it was metal spouting downpipe)   This risks making it worse.

Drill a hole for a threaded rod
Drill a hole sideways through both the outer and inner pipe.
Cut a piece of threaded rod short enough that it will just fit inside the outer pipe. Push it through the hole and thread two nuts onto it.
Tighten the two nuts against the sides of the inner pipe. Check from sides to see that it doesn't touch the sides of the outer pipe.
You now have a handle that you can attach e.g. a piece of chain or strong rope to, and then use a prybar against the top of the outer pipe to pull it up.


This is an excellent answer!

If you push a rubber expansion plug into the inner pipe and then tighten it up you might get enough grip on it to be able to pull it out.

Amazon Link
I'd suggest  tying a piece of string around the wing-nut 1st - just in case it falls in before you tighten it ...

I'm not sanguine about that working with the amount of corrosion that appears to be in the pipe.

Wood and epoxy
Take a piece of lumber that is a bit larger than the inner diameter of the pipe. Cut it with knife until the first few inches fit snugly inside the pipe.
Use sandpaper to clean the inside of the inner pipe. Mix some 2-component epoxy glue and use a stick to spread it inside the pipe. Be sure not to get any glue between the two pipes.
Push the wood into the pipe and let the epoxy cure at least overnight. You should now have a strong handle that you can drill holes into for any kind of prybar or other pulling tools you have available.
An advantage of this method is that it doesn't put much sideways pressure on the pipe.

Cut a short length of steel rod -- such as a piece of rebar -- that is ever so slightly too long to fit horizontally inside the inner pipe. Clamp the rod near its end in a set of locking pliers. Now place the rod in the inner pipe, held at a slight angle with the pliers end low, free end high. Give the high end a little tap-tap with a hammer to lock it in place. (If it doesn't lock in place, it's too long.)
Now lift using the pliers.

I'm going to suggest an alternative solution.
Leave the old pipe (grey) there.  Get a suitable length of new pipe with an Inner Diameter (ID) that is just more than the Outer Diameter of the existing pipe.
Fit it OVER the existing standpipe (black) and use construction adhesive to join them if its a loose fit.

Options: Fill the old pipe with sloppy concrete (yellow) and some rebar/reinforcing rod (red) then tap the pipe repeatedly with a hammer to vibrate all the bubbles out, and settle the concrete.   This adds strength at the bottom.   Consider filling the new pipe too, right to the top if you can, as long as its not too high.
If you want to be fancy, put a flange at the top of the new pipe to make mounting the birdhouse easier and more stable.
If you have to, bolt the new pipe to the old pipe, but be aware that's an entry point for water and future rust.   I'd go with a friction fit, or an adhesive.

I have thought about getting a 6 foot length of 2 inch plumbing pipe and putting it inside the two halves of the broken pipe, then bolting it upper and lower.
The inside of the pipe has to be hollow for the winch/pulley system that raises and lowers the housing.

One possible option is to cut the inner sleeve but it depends the length you need to work with.
If it is only 6" then there are padsws that will work or mini grinders, however if it is 18" then that becomes challenging in the extreme.
Once you have completed a cut along the length of the internal sleeve it should compress just enough to allow it to slide out.

It's almost three feet long. Interesting approach though.

A sawzall would cut at least a few inches vertically of just the inner pipe, allowing you to bend one side and get a firm grip on it with pliers.

@JonCuster I have a sawzall, so i'll definitely look into that.
